# How to send a "method" via socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, methods, byte

I'm trying to send packet made with scapy library via sockets in python 3..

That's the code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket, threading

def loop():
    global threads
    for x in range(800):
        sending().start()

class sending(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        self.connstart()

    def connstart(self):
        host = "ip" # this could be a proxy for example
        port = port # the port of proxy
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.send(self.spoofing)

    def spoofing(self):
        A = "ip" # spoofed source IP address
        B = "ip" # destination IP address
        C = RandShort() # source port
        D = port # destination port
        payload = "yada yada yada" # packet payload
        spoofed_packet = IP(src=A, dst=B) / TCP(sport=C, dport=D) / payload
        return spoofed_packet

loop()
```

Obviusly the script raises an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "spoof.py", line 12, in run
    self.connstart()
  File "spoof.py", line 19, in connstart
    s.send(self.spoofing)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'method'
```

For you is there a way to bypass this? So to send this packet unchanged?

What I wanna do is to connect to a proxy, and then send to proxy a tcp packet that contains the spoofed source ip, and the destination (different from proxy, it will be another site/server)

Answer (score 1):

The particular error you are seeing is because you aren't calling the `spoofing` method. It will go away if you add parentheses, like this:

```
s.send(self.spoofing())
```

However you have rather more serious issues. `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` returns a TCP socket, and the system will always insert the (correct) source and destination ports and addresses, as set by the `connect()` call.

If you want to do IP address spoofing you are going to have to find out how to use raw sockets and pass them directly to the data link driver - see [this example](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/856268) for a few clues as to how to proceed (and pray you aren't working on Windows, which does everything in its power to prevent raw socket access).

Comment: hi and thanks for answer. you didn't get what I extactly wanted to do with the code.. and that's my fault.. cause checking the question i posted it's not much clear.. In fact now i've added more lines at the end that explain better what I'm looking for... anyway yes.. I forgot to write the () to the call of self.spoofing. I'm running Linux :)

Comment: If you want to send a packet with a spoofed IP address the only way to do so is with the raw socket interface. If you just want to proxy, connect to the proxy and it should make its own connection to the destination (but that will have the proxy's source IP address and port number in it).

Comment: so it will be anyway useless... the only thing I'd like to do is to let proxy send this spoofed packet... cause my ISP blocks spoofed packets.. so I'm guessing if proxies could do the "dirty work" for me... so it's not possible right? sorry but I'm a newbie

Comment: You're right. Whether the spoofing takes place at the proxy or at your client, raw packet access is still required to falsify the datagram addressing information.